# forecasting trafic for many regions with time series using one model

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, python, forecasting

I am working on forecasting Trafic for many regions, each region has its own time series. I have 40 regions, i don't want to have 40 models for each Region. The question, have you an idea about one algorithm that i can forecast the trafic of all the regions at the same time?

my data is like: 01-01-2016: 20 placeA ; 
01-01-2016: 10 placeB.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Make the place an input feature. Onehot-encoded, since it is categorical

Comment: @jonnor Thank you for your response and do you have an idea which type of algorithm can I use do you have an article or a link

Comment: An RNN would be the standard ML model for time series forecasting, in particular LSTM. Though make sure to compare to ARIMA as a baseline

Comment: in fact i can not use ARIMA because i should train 40 models for each city trafic. I want to use LSTM for that but i am a liitle bit confused how can the network take only the history for each city to predict the trafic values I've seen multi state LSTM but i can't find how to implement it in python. I am new in deep learning